# Create Popup Text Field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I make a popup text field when you click in text box show big text field with a save button and a cancel button using MVC4 C# ?

Comment: It can be possible through JQUERY in MVC and logic will be in C#.
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/  .. read link... for(var i=0;i<flag;i++){ 
        jQuery(function ($){    
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
    });
         }

Answer (score 1):

You can create a popup div with css , and popup it on JavaScript onclick event of the textbox

Please refer [here](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/popup/example.php)

Answer (score 0):

if you want very simple one then use JQueryUI

```
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message
```

Very simple